# Page 2 isnt loading page navi wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set up a query to query 80 posts per page on a day date basis but it doesn't load page 2 for me. It always says 404 error. I don't really know where I have gone wrong. This is the code.

```
  <div class="mainvideoscon">
  <div class="videosallcenter">

            <?php
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('post','video', 'featured', 'spotlight'),
        'paged' => $paged
   );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if (have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    if ($current_date != get_the_date('d-m-Y')) {
        echo '<div class="datetitlecon"><header class="datetitleh"><span class="datetitlehb"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;' . get_the_date('l ') . '</span>';
        echo '' . get_the_date('dS M Y') . '</header></div>';
        $current_date = get_the_date('d-m-Y');
    }
    ?>

    <div class="mvideocontv">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="mvideocontvfi">

            <div class="gopostitem">

            <?php

                                        $posttype = get_post_type(get_the_ID());

                                        if ($posttype == "post") {

                                            echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/justlooktv/images/gonews.png">';

                                        }

                                        if ($posttype == "video") {

                                            echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/justlooktv/images/play.png">';

                                        }

                                        if ($posttype == "spotlight") {

                                            echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/justlooktv/images/play.png">';

                                        }

                                        if ($posttype == "featured") {

                                            echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/justlooktv/images/play.png">';

                                        }

                                        ?>

            </div>

            <div class="featuredimgblg"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'ftimg-home' ); ?></div>

            <?php if ('in_stock' == get_field('show_youtube_video')) { ?>  

            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<?php the_field('youtube_video_id'); ?>/mqdefault.jpg" >

           <?php } ?>

        </div></a>

        <div class="mvideodesccontv">

        <div class="ppw"></div>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php short_title('...', 58); ?></a>

        </div>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  </div>

  <div class="paginationcon">

    <div class="paginationfocus">
  <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
    </div>

  </div>


            <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing your $arg variable with this one.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array('post','video', 'featured', 'spotlight'),,
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '80',
);
```